# ISNULL formula not behaving as expected

Tags: formula

ISNULL() for currency fields is not returning true even though the value is null. I've tried != null and its still the same. 
Well the original formula is quite complex an i've narrowed it down to the below just for testing purpose. I've tried testing with other null currency values and it still seems to be not working.

```
IF(ISNULL(field__c), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Please share the code you try !

Comment: `ISNULL()` has been deprecated for a while. Salesforce suggests using `ISBLANK()` instead, which is basically the same thing, but supports text fields as well.

Comment: Also, in your formula, do you have it set to treat blanks as zeroes, or as blanks?

Comment: Don't be mistaken, simply changing your formula to use `ISBLANK()` won't fix anything, it's simply best practice.

Comment: Yes, It didn't work either. I've tried ISBLANK(field__c, 1, field__c) and it returned  0. The field is definitely null but the formula seems to be treating it as 0 rather.

Comment: Which is exactly why I asked whether your formula was set to treat blanks as zeroes, or as blanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your formula is set to treat blanks (nulls) as zeroes rather than as blanks.

If your formula is treating blanks as zeroes, then when your formula is being evaluated, it looks like this

`IF(ISBLANK(0), 1, 0)`.

As `0` is not equal to null, your formula is taking the `else` part of the `IF()` formula, resulting in `0`.

Change that setting so that your formula `treats blanks as blanks`, and your formula should work (and once more, `ISNULL()` is deprecated, and best practice is to use `ISBLANK()` instead).

Comment: Didn't notice the checkbox at all. I'm am a dev trying to fill in for an admin. Good to know new things. Thanks for your assistance.